# Way to design app that uses http requests

Tags: java

In my app I have, for example, 3 logical blocks, created by user in such order:

FirstBlock -> SecondBlock -> ThirdBlock

This is no class-inheritance between them (each of them **doesn't** extends any other), but logical-inheritance exists (for example `Image` contains `Area` contains `Message`). Sorry, I'm not strong in terms - hope you'll understand me.

Each of blocks sends requests to server (to create infromation about it on server side) and then handles responses independently (but using same implementation of http client). Just like at that image (red lines are responses, black - requests).

http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20120121/z56Sr62E.png

**Question**
Is it good model? Or it's better to create a some controller-class, that will send requests by it's own, and then handle responses end redirect results to my blocks? Or should implementation of http client be controller itself?

**P.S.** If I forgot to provide some information - please, tell me. Also if there a errors in my English - please, edit question.

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a wizard, where third block depend on second and second on first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why I would go with a separate controller class to handle the HTTP requests and responses:

- Reduce code duplication (do you really need *three* separate HTTP implementations?)
- If/when the communication protocol between your app and server changes, you have to rewrite *all* your classes. Say for example you add another field to your response payload and your app isn't built to handle it, you now have to rewrite `FirstBlock`, `SecondBlock`, and `ThirdBlock`. Not ideal.

Modify your `Implementation of HTTP client` controller class such that:

- All HTTP requests/responses go through it
- It is responsible for *routing* the responses to the appropriate class.

**Advantages?**

- If/when you change the communication protocol, all the relevant code is in this controller class and you don't have to touch `FirstBlock`, `SecondBlock`, or `ThirdBlock`
- Debugging your HTTP requests!

Comment: As I demonstate on image - there only one implementation of http client. But each class forms data by itself. Your "advantages" sounds good, but here is another question with your approach - is it a better idea to divide "http controller" to "http client" and "controller"? Or "http controller" just fine?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear.. let me clarify. By _controller_, I mean it handles _sending_ the HTTP request, as well as _receiving_ the HTTP response. So in your picture, all the **red** arrows would point to `Implementation of HTTP client` and **not** to each of First, Second, Third. In turn, the arrows going from `Implementation...` to each of First, Second, Third would be **two-way** arrows. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your 3 blocks not deal with `HttpClient` directly.  They should each deal with some interface which handles the remote connection sending of the request and processing of the results.  For example:

```
 public interface FirstBlockConnector {
    public SomeResultObject askForSomeResult(SomeRequestObject request);
 }
```

Then the details of the HTTP request and response will be in the connector implementations.  You may find that you only need one connector that implements all 3 RPC interfaces.  Once you separate out the RPC mechanisms then you can find common code in the implementations that actually deal with the `HttpClient` object.  You can also swap out HTTP with another RPC mechanism without changing your block code.

In terms of controllers, I think of them being a web-server side term and not for the client but maybe you meant a connector like the above.

Hope this helps.